# How to run restart command inside Podman container?

Tags: docker, podman

As we know Podman is dockerless, it does not have a daemon as docker.

In docker I'm able to run docker command by adding a volume in docker run  `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, with that the container can restart itself from inside with bash script.

Is there any solution to do the same thing in Podman, to run `podman restart container` within the container?

Answer (score 0):

I would not give programs access to the Docker socket (and unlimited root-level access over the host) just to restart if something goes wrong.

If you determine there's a problem and your program can't keep running, it can just exit (calling something like `exit()` or `sys.exit()` or throwing an exception that doesn't get handled).  When the main container process exits, it will trigger the container [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy), which can cause the container to restart.  [`podman run`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html) has an almost identical `--restart` option.

```sh
podman run --restart=on-failure ... my-image
```

You also might think about how you'd approach this problem if a container wasn't involved.  If you need to reload your configuration, or re-exec your own binary, or have a developer-oriented non-production live-reloading environment, those same approaches will work equally well in a container or not, and wouldn't require a Docker socket.

Comment: I agree with you, it is not recommended to give much access to the container. But exit or sys.exit will not stop the process of the container or kill it.